# [Protege]OWL- What is a slot?

Tags: rdf, owl, protege

I have been trying to understand what is a "slot" in OWL Language.
From what i understand it's the object and the data properties of a class.
Can someone please explain what is a slot, and how do i add it in Protege? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is old Protege based on frames and has nothing to do with OWL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slot concept that you refer to in Protege is as implemented in Protege up to version 3.x (version 4.0 and newer do not really have the same frame/slot architecture but are OWL oriented; the concept of slot does not really fit in OWL).

An explanation of what a frame and a slot are is available in the Javadoc for the old Protege code: http://protege.stanford.edu/protege/3.4/docs/api/core/edu/stanford/smi/protege/model/Frame.html

This should give you enough reference material to investigate further (I'm no expert on frames so I can't help much without more precise questions).

Comment: This link no longer exists